# "Geometrically, it can be viewed as the scaling factor of the linear transformation described by the matrix."

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

The sentence in the title can be found on Wikipedia with no further explanation. Could somebody tell me where I can find more about this? Does this mean that the determinant function is a linear transformation?

Comment: Which Wikipedia article? In what context?

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value of the determinant is the factor by which the volume (Lebesgue measure, more generally) changes when mapping sets under a given transformation. For example, a determinant $3$ transformation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ will map shapes to other shapes with triple the area.

The determinant is not linear; finding the volume of a shape mapped under $T_1 + T_2$ is not simply a matter of smooshing the image under $T_1$ with the image under $T_2$! It's not difficult to see, in fact, that $I$ has determinant $1$ (it doesn't change the measure of shapes), but $I + I$ has determinant $2^n$, where $n$ is the dimension of the space.

Answer (score 0):

It's very well explained in [ODE by Arnol'd V.I.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262510189) in the chapter called "The Determinant of an Operator", but anyway it's true, you can think of determinant of a $n \times n$ matrix as of linear (with respect to each one of its arguments) function with signature 
$$R^{n^2} = R^n \times \ldots \times R^n \to R,$$
where you take column vectors of a matrix as inputs of this function. Such functions are called tensors (actually, skew-symmetric tensors), you can read about it here: [Tensors - Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#As_multilinear_maps). As I remember, [Calculus on Manifolds](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805390219) also has an amazing chapter about tensors.